# ScrollIntoView Problem in keyboard navigation in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I create a autocomplete component. I add keyboard navigation. I write a function to scrollIntoView the highlighted item into screen.

```
const scrollOptionIntoView = (direction: number) => {
        if (listRef.current && highlightedIndex >= 0) {
            const optionElement = listRef.current.children[highlightedIndex] as HTMLElement;
            if (optionElement) {
                const { offsetTop, offsetHeight } = optionElement;
                const { scrollTop, clientHeight } = listRef.current;
                const optionTop = offsetTop - offsetHeight;
                const optionBottom = offsetTop + offsetHeight + scrollTop;

                if (optionTop < scrollTop) {
                    listRef.current.scrollTop = optionTop;
                } else if (optionBottom > scrollTop + clientHeight) {
                    listRef.current.scrollTop = optionBottom - clientHeight;
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

It working, fine for topSide when I click arrow up. But not working, properly when I click array down on bottom side.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmKca.gif)

Note: In the gif, First Half I click on arrow down, you could see that, it not working perfectly as when I click to arrow up, I need the same behavior as top side, In the bottom side, it need to show very bottom the highlighted part.

Here is my full component. Here I am creating a autocomplete components. I am stacking keyboard navigation when scrollIntoView.

```
const Autocomplete = ({ options }: Props) => {
    const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
    const [highlightedIndex, setHighlightedIndex] = useState(-1);
    const [open, setOpen] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const autocompleteRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
    const listRef = useRef<HTMLUListElement>(null);

    const handleChange = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        setInputValue(event.target.value);
        setHighlightedIndex(-1);
    };

    const handleKeyDown = (event: KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        if (event.key === "ArrowUp") {
            event.preventDefault();
            setHighlightedIndex((prevIndex) => (prevIndex > 0 ? prevIndex - 1 : prevIndex));
            scrollOptionIntoView(-1);
        } else if (event.key === "ArrowDown") {
            event.preventDefault();
            setHighlightedIndex((prevIndex) =>
                prevIndex < options.length - 1 ? prevIndex + 1 : prevIndex
            );
            scrollOptionIntoView(1);
        } else if (
            event.key === "Enter" &&
            highlightedIndex >= 0 &&
            highlightedIndex < options.length
        ) {
            event.preventDefault();
            setInputValue(options[highlightedIndex]);
            setHighlightedIndex(-1);
        }
    };

    const scrollOptionIntoView = (direction: number) => {
        if (listRef.current && highlightedIndex >= 0) {
            const optionElement = listRef.current.children[highlightedIndex] as HTMLElement;
            if (optionElement) {
                const { offsetTop, offsetHeight } = optionElement;
                const { scrollTop, clientHeight } = listRef.current;
                const optionTop = offsetTop - offsetHeight;
                const optionBottom = offsetTop + offsetHeight + scrollTop;

                if (optionTop < scrollTop) {
                    listRef.current.scrollTop = optionTop;
                } else if (optionBottom > scrollTop + clientHeight) {
                    listRef.current.scrollTop = optionBottom - clientHeight;
                }
            }
        }
    };


    useOutsideClick(autocompleteRef, handleBlur);

    return (
        <div className="relative" ref={autocompleteRef}>
            <Input
                label="Movie Name"
                color="indigo"
                size="lg"
                onChange={handleChange}
                onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
                value={inputValue}
                onFocus={() => setOpen(true)}
            />
            {open && (
                <ul
                    className="absolute bg-white shadow-lg rounded-md h-[300px] px-5 overflow-auto left-0 top-full z-10 w-full"
                    ref={listRef}
                >
                    {options.map((option, index) => (
                        <li
                            key={option}
                            className={highlightedIndex === index ? "bg-yellow-600" : ""}
                            onClick={() => setInputValue(option)}
                        >
                            {option}
                        </li>
                    ))}
                </ul>
            )}
        </div>
    );
};
```

export default Autocomplete;